# Curses: What's the right way to add attributes to the addstr-function?

Tags: perl, attributes, curses

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Curses;

initscr();

addstr( 5, 5, 'Hello, World!' );

refresh();
sleep 2;
endwin();
```

but if I add an attribute to the "addstr"-function it doesn't work any more:

```
addstr( 5, 5, 'Hello, World!', A_BOLD );
```

What do I need to change, to get a bold "Hello World"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addstr()` doesn't accept attributes. Use `attron()` / `attroff()` instead:

```
attron(A_BOLD);
addstr(5, 5, 'Hello, world!');
attroff(A_BOLD);
```